# Layout Weight Parameter Removed After setImageBitmap

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have a weird situation. I have a relatively simple layout with some rows and an image.

My layout looks like this (high level drawing):

[image]

The red square is an ImageView, the others are LinearLayouts and TextViews. My problem is that if i use Java code (setImageBitmap) to update the red ImageView's bitmap image then the Text 3's LinearLayout's weight seems disappear and its height will equal to the Text 3's TextView's height.

Like on this mockup (the green square is the new image):

[image]

The Text 3's LinearLayout's Weight is set to 1 so its height will force the Text 4's LinearLayout to be pushed to the bottom of the screen. So the Text 4 wont be on the bottom anymore, it jumps right after the Text 3's LinearLayout's bottom.

Here is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text 1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text2text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text 2" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Pic2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/timage" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Text3Container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text 3" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text 4" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like im using some LinearLayouts that i should not but it contains more elements in the real layout, i just stripped it a little bit to be more simple to analyse here. But generally this is my xml.

Do you guys have any suggestion why is this happening? I also tried to put the image into a FrameLayout, same...

Thanks!

Comment: I've put an answer here, maybe useful for you (bit late ;) ) http://stackoverflow.com/a/29349583/969016