# Height and view of imageview screws up after setimagebitmap

Tags: java, android, image

Here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/afterphotolayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxHeight="400dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/blankView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But In the code, when I do this:

```
_imgPreview.setImageBitmap(_compressedBitmap);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1.0f );
_imgPreview.setLayoutParams(param);
```

My image is still not resized to take up half the screen height and scale by center crop. It seems that the setImageBitmap function screws up the height/width of the imageview and doesn't allow it to be changed even after I try to set a new layout param. Can anyone shed some light on why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue! Was going crazy, setImageBitmap completely ignores the layout weight. I also added the setting of the weight programmatically:

```
barcode.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 2));
```

but did not help.
But then I did this:

```
barcode.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1, 2));
```

and that helped, not giving a '0' value for the height. I just tried this out on `lollipop`, so haven't tested in on older version, but will probably work.
Frustating, took me too long again to figure out some workaround for an Android quirk